# how to convert _list(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) into List<dynamic> in flutter 2.0

Tags: flutter, flutter2.0

I'm trying to get a List<dynamic'> _list but since I upgraded flutter to 2.0, I had to change my code to _list(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot). that type don't have length, or elementAt like normal List<dynamic'> type. it is possible to convert it?

my code:

```
List _list(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
                              return snapshot.docs
                                  .map((doc) => new Brand(
                                        doc.data()['brandId'].toString(),
                                      ))
                                  .toList();
                            }
```

later on my code I need use some fields:

```
return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                              itemCount: _list.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                Brand brand = _list.elementAt(index) as Brand;
                                return InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Brand',
                                        arguments: new RouteArgument(
                                            id: _list[index].id)
```

the error message:
error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'List Function(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>)'

any ideas are welcome, thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of now your `_list` is defined as a `Function` that returns a `List` rather than being a `List` itself.

So, in order to use it,  you should firstly properly `call` it with the necessary parameter.

Like this,

```
List myList = _list(snapshot);  // I assume you have access to a snapshot variable
return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  itemCount: myList .length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  Brand brand = myList.elementAt(index) as Brand;
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Brand',
        arguments: new RouteArgument(
        id: myList[index].id
      )
  .....
```

Comment: you need to convert the `AsyncSnapshot` to the `QuerySnapshot` by calling `.data` on it. `snapshot.data`

Comment: thank you Nisanth for your answer. unfortunately the snapshot is from firebase, so I got this type in snapshot variable: 'AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>' and when  List myList = _list(snapshot); it say _list is not defined

Comment: If `_list` is not defined then you dont have your `_list` function in the curent widget code. Post more in the question.

Comment: you're right Nisanth, I defined,  but now the error is in the line List myList = _list(snapshot.data); : The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.

Comment: Use https://pastebin.com/ and share a link after pasting your full code.

Comment: thank you Nisante, the url is: https://pastebin.com/E4LkbTYU

Comment: Check your question and check your code, you have changed the meaning of `_list1` and defined a new `_list2`. So call `List myList = _list2(snapshot.data);`

Comment: thank you Nisanth, I update the code, the url is: https://pastebin.com/u8X92Z7U - the error message now is: The argument type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>'.       - I can't find where to change to nullable, any ideas?

Comment: Change it to this, ` List _list2(
                                QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>?
                                    productSnapshot) {
                              return productSnapshot!.docs`

Comment: you rock man, it work perfectly!, thank you again for all your help, regards

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Do consider accepting and upvoting my answer

Comment: of course, is accepted :), but I don't have the ability yet to vote, (I lost my old account), when I access, I Will, thank you Nisanth and hello from Chile :)

Comment: That's alright. Have a wonderful journey with Flutter. :)